# Converting a flat table into an XML that encodes parent child relations, but without heirarchical tags

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I had an ask to convert a flat table into a particularly formatted XML which showed a parent child relationship, but had a flat structure of tags.

I produced this SQL which grinds out the result, I've added some dummy data generation so it will run standalone.

```
DECLARE @root varchar(250);
SET @root = 'AB&C';

DECLARE @index_base bigint;
SET @index_base = 9999;

DECLARE @tbl TABLE
(
    [FUNCTION] VARCHAR(20)
    ,[SUBFUNCTION]  VARCHAR(20)
    ,[LEVEL] VARCHAR(20)    
    ,[ROLE PROFILE] VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO @tbl 
VALUES
('Function 1','Sub Function 1','A','RP1')
,('Function 1','Sub Function 1','A','RP2')
,('Function 1','Sub Function 1','A','RP3')
,('Function 1','Sub Function 1','B','RP4')
,('Function 1','Sub Function 1','C','RP5')
,('Function 1','Sub Function 1','C','RP6')
,('Function 1','Sub Function 1','C','RP9')
,('Function 1','Sub Function 1','D','RP10')
,('Function 1','Sub Function 2','A','RP6')
,('Function 1','Sub Function 2','A','RP11')
,('Function 1','Sub Function 2','A','RP12')
,('Function 1','Sub Function 2','A','RP13')
,('Function 1','Sub Function 3','A','RP14')
,('Function 1','Sub Function 3','A','RP15')
,('Function 1','Sub Function 3','B','RP16')
,('Function 1','Sub Function 3','B','RP17')
,('Function 2','Sub Function 1','A','RP1')
,('Function 2','Sub Function 1','B','RP2')
,('Function 2','Sub Function 1','B','RP18')
,('Function 2','Sub Function 1','B','RP19')
,('Function 2','Sub Function 1','C','RP20')
,('Function 2','Sub Function 3','A','RP21')
,('Function 2','Sub Function 3','B','RP22')
,('Function 2','Sub Function 3','B','RP25')
,('Function 2','Sub Function 3','C','RP26')
,('Function 2','Sub Function 3','C','RP30')
,('Function 2','Sub Function 3','C','RP29')
,('Function 2','Sub Function 4','A','RP31')
,('Function 2','Sub Function 4','A','RP33')
,('Function 2','Sub Function 4','A','RP34')
,('Function 2','Sub Function 4','A','RP38')
,('Function 2','Sub Function 4','A','RP41');

DECLARE @tbl2 TABLE
(
ID bigint
,fullname varchar(max)
,parent varchar(max)
,name varchar(250)
)

INSERT INTO @tbl2
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY fullname) as ID
       ,fullname
       ,parent
       ,name
FROM
(
    SELECT 
           @root as fullname
           ,null as parent
           ,@root as name
    UNION
    SELECT distinct 
           @root + [FUNCTION] as fullname
           ,@root as parent
           ,[FUNCTION] as name
    FROM @tbl
    UNION
    SELECT distinct 
           @root + [FUNCTION] + [SUBFUNCTION] as fullname
           ,@root + [FUNCTION] as parent
           ,[SUBFUNCTION] as name
    FROM @tbl
    UNION
    SELECT distinct 
           @root + [FUNCTION] + [SUBFUNCTION] + [LEVEL] as fullname
           ,@root + [FUNCTION] + [SUBFUNCTION] as parent
           ,[LEVEL]  as name
    FROM @tbl
    UNION
    SELECT distinct
           @root + [FUNCTION] + [SUBFUNCTION] + [LEVEL]  + [ROLE PROFILE] as fullname
           ,@root +[FUNCTION] + [SUBFUNCTION] + [LEVEL]  as parent
           ,[ROLE PROFILE] as name
    FROM @tbl
) a 

SELECT [Id], [Name], [ObjectId], [ParentObjectId]
FROM
(
    SELECT a.name as [Id],  a.name as [Name], CONVERT(varchar(100), @index_base + a.ID) as [ObjectId], CONVERT(varchar(100), @index_base + b.ID) as [ParentObjectId]
    FROM @tbl2 a inner join @tbl2 b ON a.parent = b.fullname
    UNION 
    SELECT @root, @root, CONVERT(varchar(100), @index_base + 1), ''
) n
ORDER BY [ObjectId]
FOR XML PATH('Role')
```

This outputs the required XML.

Note the IDs starting with 10000 is a requirement, as is having a empty parentobjectid tag for the root element and the root element being named 'AB&C'.

The XML output looks like this

```
<Role>
  <Id>AB&amp;C</Id>
  <Name>AB&amp;C</Name>
  <ObjectId>10000</ObjectId>
  <ParentObjectId></ParentObjectId>
</Role>
<Role>
  <Id>Function 1</Id>
  <Name>Function 1</Name>
  <ObjectId>10001</ObjectId>
  <ParentObjectId>10000</ParentObjectId>
</Role>
<Role>
  <Id>Sub Function 1</Id>
  <Name>Sub Function 1</Name>
  <ObjectId>10002</ObjectId>
  <ParentObjectId>10001</ParentObjectId>
</Role>
<Role>
  <Id>A</Id>
  <Name>A</Name>
  <ObjectId>10003</ObjectId>
  <ParentObjectId>10002</ParentObjectId>
</Role>
<Role>
  <Id>RP1</Id>
  <Name>RP1</Name>
  <ObjectId>10004</ObjectId>
  <ParentObjectId>10003</ParentObjectId>
</Role>
<Role>
  <Id>RP2</Id>
  <Name>RP2</Name>
  <ObjectId>10005</ObjectId>
  <ParentObjectId>10003</ParentObjectId>
</Role>
<Role>
  <Id>RP3</Id>
  <Name>RP3</Name>
  <ObjectId>10006</ObjectId>
  <ParentObjectId>10003</ParentObjectId>
</Role>
<Role>
  <Id>B</Id>
  <Name>B</Name>
  <ObjectId>10007</ObjectId>
  <ParentObjectId>10002</ParentObjectId>
</Role>
<Role>
  <Id>RP4</Id>
  <Name>RP4</Name>
  <ObjectId>10008</ObjectId>
  <ParentObjectId>10007</ParentObjectId>
</Role>
<Role>
  <Id>C</Id>
  <Name>C</Name>
  <ObjectId>10009</ObjectId>
  <ParentObjectId>10002</ParentObjectId>
</Role>
<Role>
  <Id>RP5</Id>
  <Name>RP5</Name>
  <ObjectId>10010</ObjectId>
  <ParentObjectId>10009</ParentObjectId>
</Role>
<Role>
  <Id>RP6</Id>
  <Name>RP6</Name>
  <ObjectId>10011</ObjectId>
  <ParentObjectId>10009</ParentObjectId>
</Role>
<Role>
  <Id>RP9</Id>
  <Name>RP9</Name>
  <ObjectId>10012</ObjectId>
  <ParentObjectId>10009</ParentObjectId>
</Role>
```

ETC

This approach feels ugly.

Is there an elegant way to get the same result and make the whole thing more easily adapted. For example if an additional column and therefore hierarchy level was introduced?

Is this code at all efficient, or is there an approach I should use, elegant or otherwise, to make it perform better?

I'm currently limited to using 2008R2 (Enterprise), but would be interested in any suggestions which use more recent SQL server features.

Comment: Btw: This is a good question (due to the stand-alone example) and expected output, +1 from my side.

Comment: Just putting it out there, but any general-purpose language, Java, PHP, Python, VB can connect to your MSSQL database to retrieve a simple `SELECT` query and iteratively build the XML document in fewer lines. SQL in the end is really a special-purpose language.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I realize the XML is.. well sub-optimal is flattering. I'm told told that the legacy system that will injest it isn't

Comment: I'm told the legacy system needs this XML format. The source data is supplied by another legacy system as shown. Since this is only used to produce the transformed XML I'm not sure if shifting it 1: tables will make things any easier.

Comment: Re the second comment I know, but I don't have IDEs available to me, it's a very locked down set up. I'm not going to contemplate trying to do it in VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This design is really ugly...
I do hope, that this is an attempt to find a new design. The easiest (and best?) was to shuffle this into `1:n`-related tables.

The XML's structure is - uhm - *suboptimal*. Why do you need it this way?

This can be done as follows (needs your @tbl1 only):

- The first CTE will created partitioned ranks for easier navigation
- The second CTE will find all needed rows and find the object's id
- The third CTE will find the object's name as well as its parent id
- The final `SELECT` will add the root node

Try it:

```
WITH Ranked AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tbl.[FUNCTION] ORDER BY tbl.[FUNCTION]) AS FunctionRank
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tbl.[FUNCTION],tbl.[SUBFUNCTION] ORDER BY tbl.[SUBFUNCTION]) AS SubfunctionRank
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tbl.[FUNCTION],tbl.[SUBFUNCTION],tbl.[LEVEL] ORDER BY tbl.[LEVEL] ) AS LevelRank
          ,*
    FROM @tbl AS tbl
)
,Unpivoted AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY gr.[FUNCTION],gr.[SUBFUNCTION],gr.[LEVEL],gr.[ROLE PROFILE],gr.RecLevel) + 10000 AS RowInx
          ,*
    FROM
    (
    SELECT 1 AS RecLevel,* FROM Ranked AS r1
    WHERE FunctionRank=1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,* FROM Ranked AS r2
    WHERE SubfunctionRank=1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,* FROM Ranked AS r3
    WHERE LevelRank=1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4,* FROM Ranked AS r4
    ) AS gr
)
,Named AS
(
SELECT CASE RecLevel
            WHEN 1 THEN up.[FUNCTION]
            WHEN 2 THEN up.[SUBFUNCTION]
            WHEN 3 THEN up.[LEVEL]
            WHEN 4 THEN up.[ROLE PROFILE]
            ELSE '#Error'
       END AS Name
       ,* 
       ,CASE RecLevel
            WHEN 1 THEN 10000
            WHEN 2 THEN (SELECT MAX(x.RowInx) FROM Unpivoted AS x WHERE x.RecLevel=1 AND x.RowInx<up.RowInx)
            WHEN 3 THEN (SELECT MAX(x.RowInx) FROM Unpivoted AS x WHERE x.RecLevel=2 AND x.RowInx<up.RowInx)
            WHEN 4 THEN (SELECT MAX(x.RowInx) FROM Unpivoted AS x WHERE x.RecLevel=3 AND x.RowInx<up.RowInx)
            ELSE '#Error'
       END AS ParentId
FROM Unpivoted AS up
)
SELECT Id,Name,ObjectId,ParentObjectId
FROM
(
    SELECT 0 AS SortInx
          ,@root AS Id
          ,@root AS Name
          ,10000 AS ObjectId
          ,'' AS ParentObjectId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
          ,n.Name AS Id
          ,n.Name AS Name
          ,n.RowInx AS ObjectId
          ,CAST(n.ParentId AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS ParentObjectId
    FROM Named AS n
) AS final
ORDER BY final.SortInx
FOR XML PATH('Role')
```

The result

```
<Role>
  <Id>AB&amp;C</Id>
  <Name>AB&amp;C</Name>
  <ObjectId>10000</ObjectId>
  <ParentObjectId></ParentObjectId>
</Role>
<Role>
  <Id>Function 1</Id>
  <Name>Function 1</Name>
  <ObjectId>10001</ObjectId>
  <ParentObjectId>10000</ParentObjectId>
</Role>
<Role>
  <Id>Sub Function 1</Id>
  <Name>Sub Function 1</Name>
  <ObjectId>10002</ObjectId>
  <ParentObjectId>10001</ParentObjectId>
</Role>
<Role>
  <Id>A</Id>
  <Name>A</Name>
  <ObjectId>10003</ObjectId>
  <ParentObjectId>10002</ParentObjectId>
</Role>
<Role>
  <Id>RP1</Id>
  <Name>RP1</Name>
  <ObjectId>10004</ObjectId>
  <ParentObjectId>10003</ParentObjectId>
</Role>
<Role>
  <Id>RP2</Id>
  <Name>RP2</Name>
  <ObjectId>10005</ObjectId>
  <ParentObjectId>10003</ParentObjectId>
</Role>
<Role>
  <Id>RP3</Id>
  <Name>RP3</Name>
  <ObjectId>10006</ObjectId>
  <ParentObjectId>10003</ParentObjectId>
</Role>
<Role>
  <Id>B</Id>
  <Name>B</Name>
  <ObjectId>10007</ObjectId>
  <ParentObjectId>10002</ParentObjectId>
</Role>
[... more of this ...]
```

### UPDATE

Just in case you need it: The following code will extract `1:n`-related tables (compound key):

```
    SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY tbl.[FUNCTION]) AS FunctionRank
          ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY tbl.[FUNCTION] ORDER BY tbl.[SUBFUNCTION]) AS SubfunctionRank
          ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY tbl.[FUNCTION],tbl.[SUBFUNCTION] ORDER BY tbl.[LEVEL] ) AS LevelRank
          ,*
    INTO #Ranked
    FROM @tbl AS tbl;

    SELECT DISTINCT FunctionRank AS FunctionID
                  ,[FUNCTION] 
    INTO #Function
    FROM #Ranked;

    SELECT DISTINCT FunctionRank AS FunctionID
                   ,SubFunctionRank AS SubFunctionID
                   ,[SUBFUNCTION] 
    INTO #SubFunction
    FROM #Ranked;

    SELECT DISTINCT FunctionRank AS FunctionID,SubFunctionRank AS SubFunctionID
                   ,LevelRank AS LevelID
                   ,[LEVEL] 
    INTO #Level
    FROM #Ranked;

    SELECT DISTINCT FunctionRank AS FunctionID,SubFunctionRank AS SubFunctionID,LevelRank AS LevelID
                   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [ROLE PROFILE]) AS RoleProfileID
                   ,[ROLE PROFILE] 
    INTO #RoleProfile
    FROM #Ranked;

    SELECT * FROM #Function;
    SELECT * FROM #SubFunction;
    SELECT * FROM #Level
    SELECT * FROM #RoleProfile;
```